# Is it possible to bind a new Deployment to an existing ReplicaSet?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, azure-aks

I have some older ReplicaSets that were manually created by me, so they are not bound to/managed by a Deployment.

Is it possible to create the Deployments now, in a way that no new ReplicaSets will be created and the Deployments will automatically pair with the existing Replicasets and Pods?

I know I could delete the existing ReplicaSets, but I'm trying to find another way. I tried to give the new Deployment the same `selector` and `matchLables` as the existing ReplicaSet, but that didn't work and the Deployment created a new ReplicaSet and Pod.

Thanks!

Comment: how do your new deployment look like?

Comment: @sachin The deployment looks exactly like the existing replicaset. It has the same ```spec```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#deployment-v1-apps) resource specification does not expose any fields for specifying the initial ReplicaSet. So, the logic of creating a new ReplicaSet seems to be hardcoded in the Deployment controller.

So, the answer is, you can't do it. If you really wanted to have a Deployment where you can specify the ReplicaSet, you could create a Custom Resource Definition (CRD) and operator.

Answer (score 1):

ReplicaSets are not long lived so there is kind of no point. Just switch things over and kill the old ones.

Answer (score 1):

I think its because of `pod-template-hash` added to the labels when kubernetes does deployment so it won't match with labels of `ReplicaSet`

[image]

you can check labels added to `deployment`, I am sure labels wont be same as existing `ReplicaSets`